# phpdoc does not update my documentation

Tags: php, phpdoc

phpDocumentor v1.4.4
Fedora 24

Command line: phpdoc -d ./docsrc -t ./output

I am running phpDocumentor on Fedora 24 and have successfully generated documentation for my project one time.

I added a docblock to a function, and ran phpdoc again. But the output has not been updated. I verified the time stamps of the files and they have been regenerated, but do not reflect the changes.

I subsequently made numerous changes, and reran phpdoc after each change, but the generated documentation does not update.

I erased all the output files, renamed the directory of the input files, in short have done all I can to persuade phpdoc to generate new documentation that reflects the changes to my php files to no avail.

It would seem that phpdoc is caching the output somewhere but I cannot find where. I searched every path on my disk containing phpdoc then searched for the word "cache" in each path but it does not occur.

I tried changing the template with the --template directive but it does not recognise this directive.

I have tried using the --force directive but it does not recognise this directive.

Can someone enlighten me?

Cheers,
Peter

Comment: Are you looking at the generated PHPDoc files in a browser? If so, have you cleared the cache in the browser?

Comment: Yes I have cleared the cache, sorry I forgot to specify that. I have also viewed in both Firefox and Chrome. When I switched browsers the files could not have been in the cache since it was the first time for that browser yet it still displayed the old php doc files. Absolutely certain about the browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like one of those times where I would just walk through the process from the beginning:

- Am I modifying source in the `./docsrc` directory tree? Verify by opening the source member in `vi`/`vim`/`nano`/some-other-editor just to be sure the source has changed.
- Have I modified the source using the correct syntax? (Please post some code that shows documentation that isn't being updated)
- Modify documentation in another file with a simple change and see if that simple change appears when I regenerate my documentation.
- Am I explicitly `--ignore`-ing the file or directory I'm expecting to change? (You don't appear to be)
- Do I have a `phpdoc.xml` or `phpdoc.dist.xml` file with an `<ignore>` directive? [details](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/configuration.html)
- Do I have the necessary permissions to create/update files in the `./output` directory?
- After I've executed `phpdoc -d ./docsrc -t ./output` do I see the expected change when using `vi`/`vim`/`nano`/some-other-editor?
- Is my browser caching previous versions of the documentation? (I know you've already ruled this out Peter, I'm just trying to make my answer complete)

Comment: Thank you Benny for your lengthy and thoughtful reply. At present, the problem has solved itself. Not sure why. As to the questions above, the answer for each of them is the correct answer, so be concise. I decided to provide some code and results for the second question/suggestion. I created a small php file with a single one-line function and a doc block. I generated the doc, modified a comment, regenerated the doc and presto! It worked. I then returned to my source directory to see what was going on, regenerated all the docs and it worked.

Comment: I am not sure why. To avoid creating doc for all of WordPress I copied my own sources into a separate directory for phpdoc. Could I have been thick enough to forget to recopy after a change? I do recall copying several times. I guess I'll never know. In any event thanks for the excellent check list which will certainly prove useful going forward..

Answer (score 0):

This is EXACTLY one reason why I created [PHPFUI/InstaDoc](http://phpfui.com/?n=PHPFUI%5CInstaDoc)!  The problem with most documentation is that it is static. While that is great for libraries that don't change, if you want to document your own code, guess what?  It tends to change every day! With InstaDoc, you can see the documentation instantly on your local machine before you even check it in.  InstaDoc creates the documentation when you request the page. It is hands down the fastest documentation system out there. Most documentation systems create static pages and brag about how fast they can create the documentation.  But guess what? Who cares? What you want is to see the documentation of your current code base right now. Turns out it only takes a few seconds to scan through all the files of the libraries you are using.  InstaDoc caches that information, so you only have a long scan (and then only seconds) the first time, or when ever you add a new library.

Once you have a library scanned, the documentation comes up instantly, since it uses PHP reflection classes to read the file and display the documentation.  So that file you just modified, it is completely 100% documented. Don't like the comments, change them, refresh the page. See an issue, correct it, refresh the page. Notice something could be better? Refresh the page. Want to check out the docs on a PR? Easy, just delete the cached index and refresh the page.

InstaDoc is open source and still young. Check it out and submit comments or PR's if it does not meet your needs, but it is the future of documentation.  It will also generate static files for high volume sites, but the most important feature is that it gives you an instant reflection of your just edited code, and that is what makes it awesome.